# RBAC for default access

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Need some inputs on RBAC governance.

```
Scenario:: 
There is a role in QA READ_ROLE_QA and that has access to 2 schemas ie., 
schema_etl & schema_load

Now under schema_etl if any objects are getting created i.e., tables & view then by default who ever has access to the role "READ_ROLE_QA" is able to see those objects.

But if any object gets created under schema "schema_load" then all users who has access to the role "READ_ROLE_QA" is not able to even see those objects.
```

What inputs needed ::

1. How to ensure what access needs to be given to the role "READ_ROLE_QA" so that any object which gets created under schema "schema_load", by default are visible to the users having role "READ_ROLE_QA".
2. Currently "USAGE" privileges are there to the role "READ_ROLE_QA" for the schema "schema_load".

Appreciate any help inputs on this request.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out FUTURE GRANTS in Snowflake: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html#future-grants-on-database-or-schema-objects

The following statement gives the role READ_ROLE_QA access to all future created tables in your schema schema_load. (Other privileges like USAGE given.)

```
grant select on future tables in schema <database>.schema_load to role READ_ROLE_QA;
```